# How can I line break p tag in Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm scraping some paragraphs from a website and I occur this problem but I don't know how to resolve it.

The structure is something like this, for example:

```
<div class = "container">
   <p> This is a long paragraph 1. </p>
   <p> This is a long paragraph 2. </p>
   <p> This is a long paragraph 3. </p>
   <p> This is a long paragrahp 4. </p>
</div>
```

So I had do something like this to get the text inside the example paragraph I've just mentioned.

```
function scrapeData() {
    let data = []
    let url = `scraping-url`;
    axios(url)
    .then(response =>{
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true})

        $('.container', html).each(function(){
            const text = $(this).find('p').text()
            data.push({
              text
            })
            console.log(data)
        })

    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

But the result I get is `{This is a long paragraph 1.This is a long paragraph 2.This is a long paragraph 3.This is a long paragraph 4.}` sticking together, I want to separate these paragraphs into each chunk of text

I want it like this in my `console.log(data)`

```
{
    This is a long paragraph 1.
    This is a long paragraph 2.
    This is a long paragraph 3.
    This is a long paragraph 4.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the selector to match `p` tags, and then loop through each and construct your data.

Try this:

```
   // select p tags in the container
    $('.container p', html).each(function(){
        const text = $(this).text();
        data.push({
          text
        });
    });

    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears like this.  `{text: 'This is paragraph 1.'} {text: 'This is paragraph 2.'} ... {text: 'This is paragraph 4'}`. For more specific, I put a loop outside to scrape all the news URLs with `each` function like what you did, and I continue inside the `each` using the `each` to scrape the news paragraph inside, so if it appears like what I'm description `{text: 'info'} {text: 'info'}`, I won't know which paragraph it belongs to which news.

Comment: You said "I want to separate these paragraphs into each chunk of text", and the solution I provided allows that. Like I said, you need to construct data to fit your needs, and you can do that in the loop. JSON object is a key-value data container, it cannot have the structure you want ( `{string}`, but `{key:value}`), use `Array` for that: `data.push(text)`. If you need to track additional info, add it as properties: `data.push({whatever:data, text:text});` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you mean, I'll try that. Thanks for your instruction very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the newlines after:

```
$('p').after("\n")
```

Or when you join them:

```
$('p').get().map(p => $(p).text()).join("\n")
```